# Trying to acess the dictionary values in another function

Tags: python, dictionary

You are driving a little too fast, and a police officer stops you. Write code to compute the result, encoded as an int value: 0=no ticket, 1=small ticket, 2=big ticket. If speed is 60 or less, the result is 0. If speed is between 61 and 80 inclusive, the result is 1. If speed is 81 or more, the result is 2. Unless it is your birthday -- on that day, your speed can be 5 higher in all cases.

For this i actually thought on creating a dictionary. My first function is related to the dictionary's creation. The second one will return 0,1 or 2 depending how my input speed is. The birthay part i will solve later. I just need help in acessing the dicitionary's values

```
def code_computing():
  code_rules={'No ticket':0,'Small ticket':1,'Big ticket':2}
  return code_rules
print(code_computing())

def speed_limits():
  speed=int(input('Digit your current speed\n'))
  code_computing()
  while speed>=0:
    if 0<=speed<=60:
      traffic_ticket=code_rules['No ticket']
      print('You have only received a warning')
      return 0
    elif 61<=speed<=80:
      traffic_ticket=code_rules['Small ticket'] 
      print('You will pay  a small amount')
    return 1
    elif speed>=80:
      traffic_ticket=code_rules['Big ticket']
      print('You will pay the highest amount')
    return 2
    else:
      print('Enter a correct speed value to evaluate')
      break
print(speed_limits())
```

It gives me a syntax error in elif speed>80

Comment: Please add the traceback to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error is due to your boolean comparisons. When you use several conditions in your if statement you have to separate them as follows :

```
if 0 <= speed & speed <= 60:
```

Do this for all your conditions and you will be good to go.

Otherwise you could make several little improvements to your code. First of all you don't need a function for your dictionary. Otherwise you will create your dictionary every time you call the speed_limits function.

Here is how you could do it :

```
def speed_limits(speed, code_rules):
    while speed >= 0:
        if 0 <= speed & speed <= 60:
            traffic_ticket = code_rules['No ticket']
            print('You have only received a warning')
            return 0
        elif 61 <= speed & speed <= 80:
            traffic_ticket = code_rules['Small ticket'] 
            print('You will pay  a small amount')
            return 1
        elif speed >= 80:
            traffic_ticket = code_rules['Big ticket']
            print('You will pay the highest amount')
            return 2
        else:
            print('Enter a correct speed value to evaluate')
            break

code_rules={'No ticket':0,'Small ticket':1,'Big ticket':2}

In [1] : print(speed_limits(65, code_rules))
Out[1] : You will pay  a small amount
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your return statement `return 1` is not indented properly. Indentation is very important in python.

```
def code_computing():
    code_rules = {'No ticket': 0, 'Small ticket': 1, 'Big ticket': 2}
    return code_rules


code_rules = code_computing()
print(code_rules)


def speed_limits():
    speed = int(input('Digit your current speed\n'))
    code_computing()
    while speed >= 0:
        if 0 <= speed <= 60:
            traffic_ticket = code_rules['No ticket']
            print('You have only received a warning')
            return 0
        elif 61 <= speed <= 80:
            traffic_ticket = code_rules['Small ticket']
            print('You will pay  a small amount')
            return 1
        elif speed >= 80:
            traffic_ticket = code_rules['Big ticket']
            print('You will pay the highest amount')
            return 2
        else:
            print('Enter a correct speed value to evaluate')
            break


print(speed_limits())
```

Try the above

Comment: i have fixed the returns and it says my code_rules is not defined

Comment: code_rules was defined inside a `code_computing` function but was accessed in `speed_limits` function. So I have created a variable globally of the same name. I have pasted the code by editing. Try this.

Comment: the global variable for the code_rules has to have the function name?

Comment: variable name can be anything. Also `code_rules = code_computing()` here, we are calling code_computing function and assigning the returned value which is a dict into code_rules variable.